# Trouble with dynamic AJAX in IE?

Tags: xml, ajax, internet-explorer

I have the following problem:
I'm filling the content of some  elements using AJAX, when the user selects some option in one , then the second updates its content from the server. When the answer arrives -with Content-Type set to text/xml, I rebuild the options list in the second  element (pretty basic stuff actually).

The problem is that Internet Explorer throws an error when parsing the XML answer. In the rest of the browsers (Firefox, Opera, safari and Chrome) this script works great, but not in IE, it stills throws an error when it finds a spanish character ('ñ'). Again, I already stated the right encoding in the headers.

As an alternative i tried to change the Content Type of the answer to plain text, and then update the ´innerHTML´ property of the  elements. I tried something like this:

```
select-element.innerHTML = response-text;
```

This alternative once again seems to work perfectly in all the browsers but IE, where the property gets updated but the browser does not shows any change.

Is anyone able to help me please?
I would accept the answer to any of the two alternatives, but specially the second one (its kind of faster).

Thank you in advance!
Joshua.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to recognize that the answer is almost certainly that you didn't, in fact, specify the correct encoding in the headers. Please update your question with a sniff (e.g. use Fiddler) of the headers received, or provide the URL of a site that reproduces this problem.

You might also want to check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/02/28/script-error-c00ce56e-means-you-have-specified-an-invalid-charset-utf8-is-not-utf-8.aspx.